# proper usage of queries (Aggregates) in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

im trying to get the total count of records that are less than a value in my table so im using this query in laravel 4.2

```
$critical = DB::table('dbo_modules')
                ->where('ModuleCountLeft','<','ModuleCriticalLevel')
                ->count();
```

and passes it like this

```
return View::make('ssims.board' ,compact('title','mTotal','critical'));
```

//please don't mind the others

then receives it in the view page like this

```
<div>Modules at critical level <span><strong><?= $critical ?></strong></span></div>
```

unfortunately, im getting zero whereas in my database, i have 2 records where `ModuleCountLeft` is less than `ModuleCriticalLevel`
any ideas? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi turns out that i needed to pluck out the value of `ModuleCriticalLevel` first here is the code

```
$critical = DB::table('dbo_modules')
                ->where('ModuleCountLeft' , '<' , DB::table('dbo_modules')->pluck('ModuleCriticalLevel') )
                ->count();
```

-thumbs up here-